# Why compact() is returning an empty array inside a function?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create a function where I can pass the defined variables within a function to another function so I can extract the variables and futhur use them. Let me first show what I am trying to do so it makes more sense.

```
function naija_render( $filePath, $defined_vars )
{
    $viewData = compact(array_keys( $defined_vars ));
    extract($viewData);

    ob_start();
    include ( $filePath . '.php' );
    $template = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $template;
}
```

Now let me simplify and be specific.

if I print this

```
 print_r( compact(array_keys( get_defined_vars())) );
```

it prints the compact array however when I try to do the same thing in a function so I can just pass `get_defined_vars()` as `$defined_vars`, it prints an empty array.

```
function get_compact_defined_vars( $defined_vars ){
    //Returns blank array
    print_r( compact(array_keys($defined_vars) );
}
```

Comment: That's because functions have their own scope. They can't see any variables declared outside of them. So in the function in your last example, you are telling it to create an array out of all the variables defined by keys in `defined_vars` but it can't because the function doesn't have access to them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//something like that:
naija_render('viewfile', array('var1', 'varN'));


//rewrite your function like that:
function naija_render( $filePath, $defined_vars )
{
    $viewData = array();
    foreach ($defined_vars as $var) {
        $viewData[$var] = isset($GLOBALS[$var]) ? $GLOBALS[$var] : null;
    }
    extract($viewData);
    ob_start();
    include ( $filePath . '.php' );
    $template = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $template;
}
```

EDIT: I do not recommend this, but this do solve your problem.

Comment: That's the problem I am trying to solve by passing get_defined_vars() as '$defined_vars' so I dont have to create an array of all the variables I want to pass.

Comment: Hm.. I see. I can give you a 'not recommended' answer. Wait a sec.

Comment: Thanks Waldson, even in this case we have to pass an array of the variables we want to pass. I want to make use of get_defined_vars() and want to  know why compact() is returning an empty array in a function.

Comment: this way you have to pass array_keys(get_defined_vars()) as second parameter to make it work. like that: naija_render('view', array_keys(get_defined_vars())). Take a look at this link to understand variable scope in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php